# mustache: insert a string literal into a template filter

Tags: php, mustache

I would like to do the following (it is a template rendered by php mustache version):

```
<h1>{{hello|my_filter}}</h1>
```

Where `hello` is a literal string, not a variable name.

How can I do it?

Comment: Mustache is supposed to be logicless. You should do this treatment, using your filter in your controller, not in your template.

Comment: I would like to use gettext into the template, so, `my_filter` is a `gettext($text)` function

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've done the following:

```
<h1>{{#my_filter}}hello{{/my_filter}}</h1>
```